# Find $n$ where $\displaystyle \bigg|i+2i^2+3i^3+\cdots \cdots +ni^n\bigg|=18\sqrt{2}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Suppose that $n$ is a natural number such that $\displaystyle \bigg|i+2i^2+3i^3+\cdots \cdots +ni^n\bigg|=18\sqrt{2}$. Find the value of $n$.

What I try : Let $\displaystyle S =i+2i^2+3i^3+\cdots +ni^n\cdots (1)$

Then $\displaystyle iS =i^2+2i^3+3i^4+\cdots +ni^{n+1}\cdots (2)$

So $\displaystyle S(1-i)=i+i^2+i^3+\cdots +i^n-ni^{n+1}$

$\displaystyle S =\frac{i-i^{n+1}}{(1-i)^2}-\frac{ni^{n+1}}{1-i}=\frac{i^n-1}{2}-\frac{ni^{n+1}(1+i)}{2}$

So we have $\displaystyle \bigg|i^n-ni^{n+1}(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$

How do i find value of $n$ , please help me, Thanks

Comment: From the left hand side, it should be possible to get the real part and imaginary part of that expression (and hence the value of the modulus), first assuming that $n$ is odd and then assuming that $n$ is even.

Comment: I suspect there ain't a integer solution for $n$

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $\bigg|i^n-1-ni^{n+1}(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @hellofriends This is wrong, [there](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28%28sum+k*i%5Ek%2C+k%3D1+to+35%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2F18) are [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28%28sum+k*i%5Ek%2C+k%3D1+to+36%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%2F18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have $$\bigg|i^n-1-ni^{n+1}(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}.$$

If $n\underset{4}\equiv0$ then it becomes $$\bigg|1-1-ni(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$n\bigg|1-i\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$
$$n\sqrt{2}=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$n=36.$$

If $n\underset{4}\equiv1$ then it becomes $$\bigg|i-1+n(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$\bigg|n-1+i(n+1)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$\sqrt{(n-1)^2+(n+1)^2}=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$2(n^2+1)=2\cdot 36^2$$ $$n^2+1=36^2$$ $$n\in\emptyset.$$

If $n\underset{4}\equiv2$ then it becomes $$\bigg|-1-1+ni(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$\bigg|-n-2+ni\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$\sqrt{(n+2)^2+n^2}=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$2n^2+4n+4=36^2\cdot2$$ $$n^2+2n+2=36^2$$ $$n\in\emptyset.$$

If $n\underset{4}\equiv3$ then it becomes $$\bigg|-i-1-n(1+i)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$\bigg|-n-1-i(1+n)\bigg|=36\sqrt{2}$$ $$(n+1)\sqrt{2}=36\sqrt2$$ $$n=35.$$

The answer is: $n=35$ or $36$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:
$$\begin{align}
36\sqrt{2}&=\bigg|i^n-ni^{n+1}(1+i)\bigg|\\&=|i^n|\cdot \left|1-ni(i+1)  \right|\\&=\left|1-ni(i+1)\right| \\&=\left|(1+n)-ni\right|\\&=\sqrt{(1+n)^2+n^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: square both sides and you will have an even plus an odd giving an even number, so no natural n?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using $i+2i^2+3i^3+4i^4=i-2-3i+4=2-2i=2(1-i)$

For every $4$ pair, we get value $2(1-i)$

So for $36\sqrt{2}$, We have $9$ pairs

Means $n=36$

Answer (score -1):

$$S(1-i) = i +...+i^{n} - ni^{n+1}$$

$$S(1-i) = \frac{i(i^n-1)}{i-1} - ni^{n+1}$$

we know that $|1-i| = \sqrt{2}$, so:

$$|S| = 18 \sqrt 2 \iff |S(1-i)| = 36 \iff$$

$$\iff | \frac{i(i^n-1)}{i-1} - ni^{n+1}| = 36 \iff 36\sqrt2 = |i^{n+1}-i-ni^{n+1}(i-1)|$$

I think now you must analyze each case: $n \equiv 0, \pm 1,2 \mod 4$ and see which one works